# Reset master to an empty state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I created a new Rails app and pushed the code to Github directly from master (first commit in the repository). However I made a mistake, I didn't want to commit this new Rails app directly from master, but instead create a new branch from master and push the new Rails app from this new branch.

Therefore, I'd like to:

1. Delete the commit from master in Github(remote), so master is EMPTY
2. create a new branch from master and add the previous commit that was in master into this new branch.
3. push it to Github.

Comment: I'd suggest starting from scratch, deleting the git repository (this will help you take git away from the folder without losing files) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754152/how-do-i-remove-git-tracking-from-a-project) and starting a new one.

Answer (score 6):

> Delete the commit from the master in Github(remote), so master is EMPTY

You can create an orphan branch - orphan branch is branch without any history

```
# Create "clean" branch
git checkout --orphan <name>

# remove all existing content if you wish
git clean -Xdf && git clean -xdf
```

> create a new branch from master and add the previous commit that was in master into this new branch.

few options:

```
# Option 1 - Start your branch from the last desired commit
git checkout -b <name> <SHA-1> 

# Option 2 - Set your branch to the desired commit 
git reset <SHA-1> --hard

# Add the required commit on top of your branch
git cherry-pick <SHA-1>
```

> push it to Github.

```
# force the update of the new branch
git push <origin> master -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Please create a new branch from the master with the following command,

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

After that checkout into your new branch and push it to Github.

Now go to the master branch and [remove the last](https://gist.github.com/CrookedNumber/8964442) commit and push it to  Github

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following steps with your repository:

1. `git checkout master`: make sure you are in master.
2. `git checkout -b my-fancy-new-branch`: create your new feature branch.
3. `git checkout master`: switch back to master
4. `git reset --hard rootcommit`: reset master to the state before your own commits.
5. optional and if you have a remote you pull from: `git pull --ff` (if this fails because the pull is not fast-forward, you have to reconsider `rootcommit`. It contains some of your work)

I tried to do this on my test repository, it appears to work.

I have taken a reference from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21407249/7639034), that can help in finding other approaches too.